# CreateFile always override the specified file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I'm trying to log the actions made by a service I wrote using the Windows-API & C-language, so I made a log file system.

The problem is that at each CreateFile call, the file is overridden instead of just opening it and write at the end of the file.

Here's the code of my `WriteInLogfile` function :

```
void WriteInLogFile(LPCTSTR log_string)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dBytesWritten;

    if ((hFile = CreateFile(LOG_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
                            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        && (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
    {
        if ((hFile = CreateFile(LOG_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
                                CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            if (!WriteFile(hFile, log_string, strlen(log_string), &dBytesWritten, NULL))
                aff_error("WriteInLogFile");
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, log_string, strlen(log_string), &dBytesWritten, NULL))
            aff_error("WriteInLogFile");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

Do someone know where the issue comes from ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: By the way, you can simplify this code by using `OPEN_ALWAYS`, which tells `CreateFile` to open the file if it exists or to create the file if it doesn't.  Then you won't have to duplicate so much of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you're opening the existing file you're not specifying that you want to append to it.  Hence it opens as a generic write and you end up overwriting the contents.  You need to pass the `FILE_APPEND_DATA` flag to the `CreateFile` method.  This is best done by using the `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` flag which includes `FILE_APPEND_DATA`

```
if ((hFile = CreateFile(LOG_FILE_PATH, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
                            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        && (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
    {
```

Comment: This works fine. Do you know if there's a way to keep newlines with this ? It seems that it skips mine...

Comment: @tsabz new lines shouldn't be changed if you use this flag. Are you having a problem writing them out?  You may need to add them manually as `WriteFile` itself won't add them for you .

Comment: I make my call to the function like this : `WriteInLogFile("LOG: somethingtowrite\n");` and it doesn't keep the newline.

Comment: @tsabz Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: Using `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` didn't work for me. Directly using `FILE_APPEND_DATA` did! Wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file, the pointer will always be positioned to the beginning of the file. To append, you need to explicitly seek to the end (`SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END);`).

Although it may not be causing your actual problem, I'd replace your current logic trying to use `CreateFile` with `OPEN_EXSTING`, then with `CREATE_NEW` if the first attempt fails. Instead, just pass the `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag, which pretty much automates that logic -- open an existing file if it exists, and create a new one if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed your answer with JaredPar's one and all is going better now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the file pointer to the end of the file before writing with [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See the MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900134.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see anything obvious about opening for Append in the CreateFile documentation, but you could use the [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
 function to seek to the end of the file before writing.